# cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in exit status 2 exit status 1

Tags: node.js, go, npm, nodes

I get this error when i try to build my go project.

Any idea what this error means and how this can be resolved.

FYI: this project also uses nodejs assets.

Comment: This might help https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3441.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This error is usually caused by having a 64bit Go and 32bit MinGW gcc installed in PATH

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2602

You can check your MinGW version with:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32 --build=m
ingw32 --without-pic --enable-shared --enable-static --with-gnu-ld --enable-lto
--enable-libssp --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++
,ada --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-win32-registry --enable-l
ibstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gmp=/usr/src/pkg/gm
p-5.1.2-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpc=/usr/src/pkg/mpc-1.0.1-1-mingw32-src/bld --
with-mpfr= --with-system-zlib --with-gnu-as --enable-decimal-float=yes --enable-
libgomp --enable-threads --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw32 --with-libintl-prefix=/
mingw --disable-bootstrap LDFLAGS=-s CFLAGS=-D_USE_32BIT_TIME_T
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)
```

Comment: Hello Alex Efimov, actually i have not installed mingw, i tried installing from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/ and from https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php but it didn't work. That is why i posted this question online. Can you please suggest me how to install the proper 64-bit mingw.

Comment: FYI: Am using windows machine

Comment: What impediments where there? What version of windows are you using?

Comment: You could install https://cygwin.com/install.html for 64-bit system, it contains mingw.

Comment: AM using windows7. Am using go1.8 of 64 bit, when i build my project i get the above error and i have to install gcc (done through mingw). Plus "gcc -v" gives the error  'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @KiranKumar: I use [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download) for the TDM64 MinGW-w64 edition.